# Weird error with Cocoa-Touch (SIGABRT while trying to input two image view)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, imageview, sigabrt

I'm with some really weird problem here. 
Every time when I add a second image view, the program crash: "Couldn't register ken.word with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(gdb)" (SIGABRT)

it goes SIGABRT on this part of the code:

```
   return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

but when I just add one image view, it goes perfectly well. 
I've tried to restart the Xcode, even restarting the mac, and it didn't work.
I've also tried to create another project, and it didn't work either!

I'm using Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quit your XCode and Simulator then try again. It will work. And never quit your simulator when it is in running mode, first stop the program then quit.

And if you are running your app in your device then delete your app from device, switched OFF your device then ON and try.

Comment: I've got the same error. 
I killed the program, then quit the Xcode. but I'm still having the same issue. I'm emulating on the Ipod

Comment: Hey if you are running your app in device then switch it off and on again then try..... You should had to mention this in your question

Comment: to quit the simulator you only need to click on the "Stop" button right?
If its not, how to do it?

Comment: nope, right click on simulator icon which is visible in below tool bar, you will see an option for quit. And if your are using device then see my edited answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks.
Its now working on the simulator, but not on the device.
I need to switch the iPod off?

Comment: YES, Switched off your device then on and try

Comment: THANKS! 
Sorry for my misunderstandings!